# how to get all the photos uploaded in instagram for a specific location

Tags: java, media, instagram, photo

I went through the API documentation for /media/recent, but it does not specify what is the duration for which we receive the media files for a specific location.

They have mentioned that we could pass the below parameters to the API.

1. MIN_TIMESTAMP
2. MAX_TIMESTAMP

Can anyone give me an example on how to pass this value to the API?

Also is there any API exposed to get the total number of photos for a specific location in instagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the medis.search endpoint:

```
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search
```

you have to pass `lat` and `lng` for location, `max_timestamp` and `min_timestamp` are option and can be specified in epoch time.

here is example:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?max_timestamp=1410332400&distance=1000&lat=37.8062&lng=-122.4738&access_token=XXX
```

Here is an implementation using this API, you can search by location and filter by date:
http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have the location id. (1) By passing the location id, i need to get all the media records for the location. (2) Do you know how recent are the 'recent/media' API results are?

Comment: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/#get_locations_media_recent you can get all media by using pagination, you check here: www.gramfeed.com/instagram/places, search for place and get all photos

Comment: Hi... I want to make an API call. How would I use gramfeed.com for that. The link API with endpoint '/locations/location-id/media/recent' does not have pagination..

Comment: gramfeed.com is a implementation, u have to use /locations/location-id/media/recent' , it does have pagination, if there is not, then that location has less than 20 photos, try another location

Comment: Thanks.. Does instagram feed give us the photo count for the place?